# what is the reason for subtracting 1 from the randint return value?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not understanding the reason for subtracting 1 from the the retuen value of randint method to gain a random number, could some one please explain this to me?

```
import random

def random_item(iterable):
    randomIndex= random.randint(0, len(iterable))-1
    item=iterable[randomIndex]
    return item
```

Comment: How is this a typographical error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*randint*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) ***includes** the upper bound*:

*Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.*

If you used `iterable[len(iterable)]` you would get an *IndexError* so the  `random.randint(0, len(iterable)) - 1` ensures that if you get a random int equal to the length of the iterable that does not happen.

On a side note, using `random.choice(iterable)` would be a better idea and remove the need to worry about indexe erros although you have a slightly higher chance of getting the last element with the current implementation which may or may not be intentional.